# Android Corporate Lockdown

Tags: android

Is their an android equivalent to the Apple configuration policy?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html

We are deploying some android tablets (company owned) in a corporate environment and need to lock down specific features in the tablets.  Mainly to turn off the camera and the lock which applications can be run.  Possibly forcing install of certain applications.

Comment: http://www.itworld.com/mobile-wireless/212017/enterprise-management-tools-coming-android Maybe, you can start thinking on Samsung Knox enterprise Android solution http://www.samsung.com/global/business/mobile/platform/mobile-platform/knox

Comment: Sadly, these are not Samsung devices.  Someone purchased two cheap tablets and they got dumped on me because no one can figure out how to make them secure.  Which it seems to me that the only way to do this is to root them and install a custom built OS.

Answer (score 1):

> Mainly to turn off the camera

That is supported via [the device administration API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html).

> the lock which applications can be run

There is nothing in the Android SDK for this.

> Possibly forcing install of certain applications

There is nothing in the Android SDK for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try out android for work..

https://www.google.com/work/android/features/

It should give you ways to remotely administer android devices.

> App security
>
> Work apps are deployed through Google Play for Work. IT can prevent
>   installation of apps from unknown sources and apply app
>   configurations.